# Modifying a data.table to only include unique values of one variable

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that I wish to modify. The data.table has many columns, *n* of which I am interested in, let us say for this example "cyl", "hp" and "gear" from mtcars are of interest. I want to make a new data table with only these three columns, with rows only of unique values of one of the three. This is what I have so far:

```
  dt <- data.table(data)[, .(cyl, gear, hp)]   
  dt[,unique(gear),by=.(cyl,hp)]
  dt[,!duplicated(dt[,gear])
```

Is there a better way to do this, and could somebody help me understand how I can make this into a function where I specify the data, and variables of interest? My attempt so far:

```
fun_plot_gam <- function(data,var,var_list){
  var_list = c("cyl","gear","hp")
  var = "gear" #variable I'm interested in
  var_list2 = var_list[which(var_list != var)]

  dt <- data.table(mtcars)[, var_list, with=FALSE]
  dt[,unique(var), by=var_list2,with=FALSE] #problem line
  dt[,!duplicated(dt[,var])]

return(dt)
```

}

It seems that I don't understand the data.table properly to make a function out of this. If anybody could guide me in a direction to quickly understand when to use "get", ":=" and dots within functions manipulating data.tables I would be grateful =)

Comment: [This alternative](https://asardaes.github.io/table.express/articles/table.express.html#distinct-combinations-of-columns) might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks Alexis :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `get` the value of the 'var' with `get`

```
dt[,unique(get(var)), by=var_list2]
```

-fullcode

If  we are passing 'data' and other arguments in function, there is no need to specify it outside (just beats the purpose of the function)

```
fun_plot_gam <- function(data,var,var_list){

  # get the vector of column names that are not in the 'var'
  var_list2 <- setdiff(var_list, var)

  # convert to data.table, subset the columns 
  dt <- as.data.table(data)[, var_list, with=FALSE]
  # get the `unique` elements of column specified in 'var' 
  # grouped by 'var_list2' columns
  dt1 <- dt[, unique(get(var)), by=var_list2]
  setnames(dt1, ncol(dt1), var)
  dt1

}

fun_plot_gam(mtcars, var, var_list)
#    cyl  hp gear
# 1:   6 110    4
# 2:   6 110    3
# 3:   4  93    4
# 4:   8 175    3
# 5:   6 105    3
# 6:   8 245    3
# 7:   4  62    4
# 8:   4  95    4
# 9:   6 123    4
#10:   8 180    3
#11:   8 205    3
#12:   8 215    3
#13:   8 230    3
#14:   4  66    4
#15:   4  52    4
#16:   4  65    4
#17:   4  97    3
#18:   8 150    3
#19:   4  91    5
#20:   4 113    5
#21:   8 264    5
#22:   6 175    5
#23:   8 335    5
#24:   4 109    4
```

Comment: It looks like a lot of duplicate rows there?

Comment: @Helen here, your function gets the `unique` elements which can be mor ethan one per each group.  e.g. `cyl -6 and hp - 110` have gear unique values 4, 3

Comment: if you needd as a list column wrap with list, or a string use `toString(unique(get(var)))`

Comment: Ah so sorry! I meant, what if I want a subset with only unique values of «var»?

Comment: @Helen It is giving only a ssubsset of unique values by group, please check the values you got